# Can Firefox display only certain bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I have *many* bookmarks, but I don't want to always have them show up in the drop down menu of the omnibar (where you enter the url). Is it possible to select which ones to display and which ones not to?

Answer (score 1):

Though I know of no way to "hide" a bookmark *within Firefox*, there are alternatives to make finding them easier.

1. Make a folder on your *Desktop*, in the *Start Menu* or another convenient location for your infrequently used bookmarks, drag your infrequently used bookmarks to that folder and then delete them from Firefox.
2. For each bookmark you can add tags, a keyword and a description to make your search more specific. Invent your own tags for the frequently used ones; e.g. **>map** for all maps. Because it begins with the GT symbol, it won't show all your *math* shortcuts, as it would if you type "ma" in the search box.
3. Organize bookmarks by folder rather than use *Search:*. You have a choice of putting bookmarks in the Firefox *Bookmarks Toolbar*, the *Bookmarks Menu* and *Unsorted Bookmarks* default folders, some of which can be left expanded or not at your discretion. However, *Search:* lists bookmarks in *all three* folders and their subfolders.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you double-click on the white star to bookmark a URL, a pop-up window  appears with three spin boxes: Name, Folder and Tags. If you set the Folder to Unsorted Bookmarks, the bookmark will not appear in the Bookmarks Bar.

If you click on the clipboard icon to the right of the star and choose Show All Bookmarks, or do {Ctrl-Shift-B}, you can see all bookmarks, and drag-and-drop them into Unsorted Bookmarks to remove them from the Bookmarks Bar. You can also create folders, both in and out of the Bookmarks Bar, to organize the bookmarks.

I have multiple folders in the Bookmarks Bar to organize the bookmarks into categories. You can create folders alphabetically by the name of the website or in any other way you wish.